# Execute select query in where condition

Tags: sql-server, database, while-loop, increment, sql-query-store

I want to execute a select query in where condition for update table to fill number increment as per user account in SQL Server.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
WHILE @i <= 1077
begin   
    update tbl_UdharKhata set ReceiptNo = @i 
    where EXISTS (select distinct UserId from tbl_udharkhata)
    SET @i = @i + 1;    
end
```

this query is working perfectly but the problem is that in `ReceiptNo` whole user account receipt number updating the same number.

Note: there are 1077 rows of distinct user accounts and hence there is 1077 row of userid.

Comment: It seems that you want to update 1077 records in your table.  Can you clearly articulate the logic for _which_ 1077 records should be getting the update?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include [proper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is updating all the records in the table 1077 times, each time with a different number, up to the end of the loop. Now I'm not sure if you want a single number for each `userId`, or an incrementing number for each row with the same `userId`, starting at 1 for each `userId`.

The only way for your `SELECT` statement to not return anything is if the table is empty - because it has no `WHERE` clause.
Since your `select` statement is in an `EXISTS` operator, the condition will always evaluate to `true`, making the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement redundant.

basically, it's like `update tbl_UdharKhata set ReceiptNo = @i where exists(select 1)`,
which is exactly like `update tbl_UdharKhata set ReceiptNo = @i`

This means that in each iteration of the loop, you're updating all the records in the table with the current value of `@i`.

Now, it's not very clear from your question what you want, but I'm gonna go on a limb here and guess you want to update the `ReceiptNo` column so that for each `userId` you'll have an incrementing number, resetting to 1 for each new userId.
If that is the case, the easiest way to do that is by creating a common table expression (cte) and then update that cte:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ReceiptNo
           -- Note: Order by @@SPID means an arbitrary order! Details after the code.
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY @@SPID) As Rn
    FROM tbl_UdharKhata 
)

UPDATE cte
SET ReceiptNo = Rn
```

Note I've used `ORDER BY @@SPID` in the `OVER` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

`@@SPID` is a built in function that returns the session ID of the current user process - meaning that it will return a constant value in each session.
Using `Order by` with a constant value will generate an arbitrary order.

If you want a specific order, use any column in your table that isn't `userId` (otherwise you'll end up with the same arbitrary order - because the `userId` will be the same for each partition).